# BroadcastReceiver on new app installs

Tags: android, package, broadcastreceiver, android-intent

I want to receive a notification when a new application is installed.

```
IntentFilter newAppFilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED);
newAppFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_CHANGED);
newAppFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_INSTALL);
newAppFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_REPLACED);
getApplicationContext().registerReceiver(newAppReceiver, newAppFilter);


public static BroadcastReceiver newAppReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {     
            Log.e("Broadcast","Received");
       }
};
```

But I am not able to get any log. Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 10):

Try to add data scheme to your `IntentFilter`.

```
newAppFilter.addDataScheme("package");
```

Reference: [IntentFilter.addDataScheme()](http://d.android.com/reference/android/content/IntentFilter.html#addDataScheme%28java.lang.String%29) documentation

> If no schemes are included, then an
>   Intent will match only if it includes
>   no data.

Answer (score 2):

If anyone runs across this, the intent documentation now says:
[ACTION_PACKAGE_INSTALL - This constant is deprecated. This constant has never been used.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_PACKAGE_INSTALL)